# Why does initial value overwrite existing data on django forms?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to add an initial value to a form. But the initial value is overwriting the actual form data.

```
class TempForm(forms.ModelForm):
    initial = {'invoicedate' : datetime.now().date()}
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['initial'] = self.initial
        super(TempForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

For example Invoice ABC has an actual invoicedate of 1/1/2020 but if I open the page for that invoice right now the field displays 6/6/2020 (today's date).

The form is called from an UpdateView's custom `get_form_class` method. 
According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#initial) the initial value is used "when rendering this Field in an unbound Form". So I'm wondering if my form is unbound perhaps. How do I check if a form is unbound or not? And is there any issue with how I established initial values here?

invoicedate in `models.py`:

```
invoicedate = models.DateField(db_column='InvoiceDate', null=True, verbose_name = 'Invoice Date')
```

Comment: Can you share (relevant parts) of the model and the view?

Comment: Thanks. I added the field from models.py. The view is pretty big. I overwrite several methods like get_queryset, form_invalid, form_valid, etc. Anything specific you think might be relevant?